# Select a single element from a complex ID

Tags: r, plot, text, label, element

I have IDs such as "3_K97_T12_High_2_Apples". I want to select just "T12" and store it in a character vector (Tiles) so I can call it in text() when I label my points in the plot() with label =  Tiles. I want to label each point with just the 3rd element of the ID (i.e T12).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex to extract - capture the third set of characters that are not a `_` (`([^_]+`) from the start (`^`) of the string as a group and in the replacement specify the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
Tiles <- sub("^[^_]+_[^_]+_([^_]+)_.*", "\\1", str1)
Tiles
[1] "T12"
```

`^` - start of the string

`[^_]+` - one or more characters not a `_`

`_`  - the `_`

`[^_]+` - one or more characters not a `_`

`_` - the `_`

`([^_]+)` - one or more characters not a `_` captured

#### data

```
str1 <- "3_K97_T12_High_2_Apples"
```

Comment: Can you explain what the code is doing? Thank you.